# Git Hub Error While uploading my react project on github

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github

Error show ->

remote: Permission to truptichoudhari16/React-Dashboard-.git denied to truptich1.

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/truptichoudhari16/React-Dashboard-.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Please Help me to resolve my error and give me suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Reread the permission error. The account you are trying to push with is a different account than the one the repository belongs to. Your account truptich1 likely has no push permission to that repository belonging to user truptichoudhari16.

Reconfigure your git configuration to use the user truptichoudhari16.